# sql server - multiply values by themselves

Tags: sql-server, multiplication

there is a way for aggregate values in multiplication (*) operator rather than + Operator?. for this example the result will be 140 (4*5*7=140)

```
SELECT  SUM(V) --*?
FROM    ( SELECT    4 V
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    5
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    7
        ) Q
```

Comment: Nothing built in. You'll probably need to use a cursor and do the calculation yourself. Otherwise do it on the client. But also note range of ints on SQL Server: you'll not need many rows before overflowing (compound multiplication of even small values greater than one gets big quickly).

Comment: where are these values stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       select *
    into #a --*?
    FROM    ( SELECT    4 V
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    5
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    7
            ) Q

 select EXP(SUM(LOG(v))) As value from #a
```

or

```
SELECT  EXP(SUM(LOG(v)))
FROM    ( SELECT    4 V
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    5
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    7
        ) Q
```